# Calculated SSAS Measurement using Dimensional Attribute

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to calculate a measure based on an attribute in a dimension I have. Never done this before and keep getting errors so thought I would reach out for help. One of my dimensions is an Items dimension and it holds an attribute called Contribution Cost. I also have a measure on my fact table called Net Sales Amount. If there is no cost on a specific item, I want to calculate a Contribution Margin off a percentage of Net Sales, otherwise I want it to simply take the net sales minus the contribution cost. This is what I wrote but could someone help me?

```html
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Contribution Profit]
 AS CASE WHEN SUM([Items].[Contirbution Profit]) = 0 THEN SUM(measures.[Net Sales Amount2]) * .6
ELSE SUM(measures.[Net Sales Amount2]) - SUM([Items].[Contirbution Cost]) END, 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0;$#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```